# how do I save custom user control viewstate during postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have written the user control InputDetails that has a few text boxes and a few radio boxes inside it.

I add it dynamically during Page_Load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack()){
  InputDetails input = (InputDetails)Page.LoadControl("InputDetails.ascx");
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(input);
}
```

but when I refresh the page, the control is gone, so I'm asking, how do I save the user control in the viewstate that it has been added, so it automatically reloads it next time. Better yet, how do I read the values put in the text boxes of the user control when the page is posted back? I need to be able to add multiple InputDetails on a single page so saving it would be useful.

Comment: As Lucas has mentioned, remove the Postback-Check and it works. Dynamically created controls must be recreated on every postback. ASP.NET will automatically restore values(like `TextBox.Text`) from ViewState if you don't change controls' ID's manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a control to the page dynamically, you have to recreate it after each postback. 
Try to remove the **if (Page.IsPostBack())** line and check if it works :). 
For each control you create, you should also set the same ID value each time it's created. 
If there are no other issues, the ViewState should then be able to save state of the controls across postbacks.

In order to read the values, you can:

- add some public properties to your user control in order to get access to the values you need
  or
- use **TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)myCustomControlObject.FindControl("nestedTextBox")** method to find (more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can load user controls / server control dynamically using AJAX also and   viewstate requires  controls ID to store the viewstate properly.

would you pls go through this link for [more info](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/maintain-viewstate-for-dynamic-controls-across-the-postback/)

Comment: ASP.NET will retain ViewState for dynamic control even if you don't assign ID's explicitely because the ID will be created according to the control's position in it's par ent container(PLaceHolder in this case). Besides, AJAX has nothing to do with this question.